# Help!!! RegEx.Replace

Tags: c#

How do i achieve this directory format using the RegEx.

```
Input FileName(40 chars) : 000a2d0e62e43b0f680a6eb6019f9671b15ca291

output should looks like this: 00\0a2\d0e\62e43  
get only the first 13th character.
```

Thanks a lot.

johnL

Comment: What is the final form, past the first few bytes? What is the regex you're using now, what does it spit out? Post some code, if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What determines a directory names?  The length?  What happens to everything else?  Assuming the first requires 2 characters, second and third requires 3, the last requires 5 and the rest are thrown out, you could do this:

```
var str = "000a2d0e62e43b0f680a6eb6019f9671b15ca291";
var pattern = @"^(\w{2})(\w{3})(\w{3})(\w{5})";
var output = Regex.Match(str, pattern).Result(@"$1\$2\$3\$4");
```